# CORS issue with Angular frontend and Python Backend

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask, cors

I have setup a flask based api backend like this.

```
from datetime import timedelta  
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, current_app, jsonify
from functools import update_wrapper

app = Flask(__name__)


def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None, max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True, automatic_options=True):  
  if methods is not None:
    methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
  if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
    headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
  if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
    origin = ', '.join(origin)
  if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
    max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

  def get_methods():
    if methods is not None:
      return methods

    options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
    return options_resp.headers['allow']

  def decorator(f):
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
      if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
      else:
        resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
      if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
        return resp

      h = resp.headers

      h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
      h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
      h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
      if headers is not None:
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
      return resp

    f.provide_automatic_options = False
    return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
  return decorator


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def landing():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.data
    return 'God saved the post'
  else: 
    return jsonify(i_am_a='cross domain resource!')


if __name__ == '__main__':  
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Now I am making rest calls to this app backed using the an angular from end like this in an angular container.

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
     .success(function(gdata) {
       $scope.gdata = gdata;
     });
var pdata = {'message': 'i am post data'}; 
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080', pdata)
     .success(function(pdata) {
       $scope.pdata = pdata;
     });
```

My GET is successful, but I am faced with CORS issue when there is POST. Has someone got this working, would need help on this.

Comment: Even tried adding the $httpProvider as mentioned on many answers on this site. Like this.
`.config(function($httpProvider) {`
`$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;`
`delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];`
`})`
`...`

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to ur controller
i had the same problem earlier

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flask-CORS in your Python Backend, this will solve the CORS issues

Documentation here: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/